# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in collection runner

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

While executing my script in postman collection runner, I am getting following error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` .But the same is working fine while executing single script from postman(clicking "send" button instead of executing from runner)

API RESPONSE:

```
{
    "Result": true,
    "Reason": [],
    "SanitizedData": [],
    "RawData": [
        {
            "name": "area1",
            "warehouse_id": "103",
            "warehouse_name": ""
        }
    ],
    "Columns": [
        "name",
        "warehouse_id",
        "warehouse_name"
    ],
    "S3FileURL": "",
    "mdmLogId": "179"
}
```

CODE:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("Area_Name", jsonData.RawData[0].name);
```

Comment: Add `console.log(jsonData)` to see what's really there.

Comment: Most probably `responseBody` is not the expected response. It's certainly JSON string (`JSON.parse` throws an error if the input is not a valid JSON), but not what you want.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks for your reply .You are right responce is returning false.As per the log Request Body one parameter is not being sent , 
        
As per log:

data[id]: " 1"
data[uploadtype]: " insert"

one more parameter  data[file] (this is attachmnt file) is missing in the request body eventhough this parameter is selected for posting along with API